# I'm writing software that will be tracking files and if they are changed, should I be using UTC

Tags: utc

I'm writing some software to track if a file has been checked out and changed. The file could be checked out and changed by various people in several different time zones.

So, simply put I would be doing something like this:

```
if ( checked_out_file.last_modified_date > my_database_record_of_the_last_modified_date ) {
     // file has changed since last sync so do something
}
```

The above is just pseudo-code so don't get hung up on what language and things like that. What I am basically wondering is should I store the `my_database_record_of_the_last_modified_date` as the UTC time, and when I do my `checked_out_file.last_modified_date` comparison, as illustrated in my pseudo-code above, should I also use the UTC time for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time is a pain to work with.  Time zones are even worse.  There's not much you can do about that.  But if you use UTC *everywhere*, you can make time a little more bearable.

Store all your dates in UTC.  Do all your date comparisons in UTC.  Do everything you possibly can in UTC.  Ideally, the only time a date *won't* be in UTC is when it's being formatted for display to a user.  Time zones are a rabbit hole you do *not* want to go down.

Hope this helps!

PS:  Yes, I've had bad experiences with time zones in the past.  Could you tell?

Comment: Would you like to say a few words about POSIX time_t values and UTC leap seconds, as long as you're on a roll?  +1 from me because I feel your pain.

Comment: @Jim I can get it down to one word: "Gaaah!"  I haven't had to deal with leap seconds yet (fingers crossed), but I love how the [Wikipedia time_t page](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Time_t) sounds like it was written by yet another disgruntled programmer...  Cheers!